# Proofreading romantic novels

Tags: halal-haram

AsA. I've been working as a freelancer for quite some time now. I mostly get projects related to proofreading. Sometimes, the stories I get to proofread romance novels and stuff. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Whats wrong with romance? Islam is not about wearing a hair-shirt and being an abstinent about all the pleasures of in life. Its about not indulging in them to excess, so that it harms both you, others and society.

For example, I was listening to a DJ on the radio and she was saying how she now has tinnitus which, if she focuses on it, would drive her crazy and she wishes she was told about the damage that loud music can do to hearing at school.

Likewise, Islam is not against romance, but against hedonism.

Comment: I like your last line. I think it kinda explains how some christian denominations (or at least their local autonomous/particular/whatever churches, as i recently discovered in an episode of 'young sheldon') are against 'dances' (despite psalm 149 and 2 Samuel 6:14-22). it's not that they're against the act of 'dancing' but against the possible immoral acts or temptations to possible immoral acts that may occur at these 'dances'. (afaik, i'm not in 1 of those denominations, but i can at least respect those denominations assuming my understanding is correct)

Comment: @BCLC: Dancing isn't against Islam - but hedonism is. That's the point I am making.

Comment: Right yeah that.